# The issue with the first time load Extract tableau report on the tableau server:- First time - Report load time on Tableau server 5 min ,2nd 4 sec

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I have one issue with first the time-loading report on the Tableau server. It takes 5 min to load the report on the Tableau server; the second time, it takes only 4 sec. (means after closing and re-open the report on the Tableau server )

the issue is highlighting one dashboard, designing 14 worksheets connected and 2 filter

I am not able to understand the issue.

Report; I have 8 dashboards and 4 data source

Option: Try to resolve the issue but not resolve it now

Tableau server upgrade 2022.2 to 2023.2
in place of a data source with a workbook, I used a published data source with a Tableau report.
applied context filter and hide the unused field
create extract as data aggregated
Enable cache on tableau server for site
Can anyone pls help me for this issue ?

Can anyone pls help me for this issue ?

Comment: Use Tableau Cloud, its much better

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the original request not having any cached data to pull from. Once the second request is made the data has been cached and you see the quicker times. Even if you close the report, the data is still cached for some time based on the server configuration. You can force the data to be cached (warming the cache) to have the initial request of the workbook be as quick.

Warming the cache involves creating a subscription to the view that will send a thumbnail of the workbook via email before the workbook is required throughout the day. Follow this guide to set it up. You have Tableau Cloud tagged, but if you are on server, you can extend the time that the cache will be saved.

[How To Warm Cache](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/warming-the-tableau-server-cache-using-subscriptions)

Comment: Hi Vizyourdata,

Thanks for the reply.
we can not Schedule Extract refresh.
Currently, we are refreshing the dashboard manual as per the client's requirement>because our data is not comming weeky , monthly so .

Can you give me the input for any other way that we can fixe the issue ?